# Adding @StepScope to ItemWriter causes ClassCastException: $Proxy57 cannot be cast to ItemStream

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a step in spring batch job that is defined as so. Please note that I am only including what I think is relevant.

```
@Bean
public Step readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep(
        @Qualifier("queryStagingDbReader") ItemReader<MasterList> queryStagingDbReader,
        @Qualifier("masterListOutputProcessor") ItemProcessor<MasterList,MasterList> masterListOutputProcessor,
        @Qualifier("masterListFileWriter") ItemWriter<MasterList> masterListFileWriter,
        @Qualifier("divisionMasterListFileWriter") ItemWriter<MasterList> divisionMasterListFileWriter,
        @Qualifier("stepListener") CustomStepExecutionListener stepListener) {

    return  commonJobConfig.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep")
                .<MasterList,MasterList>chunk(commonJobConfig.chunkSize)
                .reader(queryStagingDbReader)
                .processor(masterListOutputProcessor)
                .writer(masterListFileWriter)
                .stream((ItemStream) divisionMasterListFileWriter)
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();               
}
```

Where divisionMasterListFileWriter is defined like so.

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<MasterList> divisionMasterListFileWriter() {

    FlatFileItemWriter<MasterList> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(commonJobConfig.outDir, "45_masterList" + "" + ".csv")));
    writer.setHeaderCallback(masterListFlatFileHeaderCallback());
    writer.setLineAggregator(masterListFormatterLineAggregator());
    return writer;
}
```

I now have a requirement to change divisionMasterListFileWriter to @StepScope because I need to access something from the stepExecutionContext.

The problem is as soon as I add @stepScope to divisionMasterListFileWriter I start getting ClassCastException when I try to run...

```
Error creating bean with name 'readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep' defined in ExportMasterListCsvJobConfig:  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream
```

It seems like adding @stepScope to the writer is breaking the .stream part of the step definition.

Can someone please help me with what I can do to fix this?

I'm not sure but maybe this is related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2023 ? I also tried the below after finding that jira link but it didn't change anything.

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

thanks

Comment: Change the return type of the method to `FlatFileItemWriter<MasterList>`. The java config looks at the return type of the method to determine what to proxy, in your case that is only `ItemWriter` it doesn't inspect the runtime object as there is no object at that moment.

Comment: thanks. This solved my problem. But also has improved my understanding of how java config works in spring.

Comment: Thanks too. This comment should be an accepted answer.

Comment: I have the same problem when mixing @Component and XML configuration. Defining the beans in XML config with `scope="step"` worked for me. No idea why. Maybe @MichaelMinella knows?